# Google Tag Manager / Analytics wrong accounts

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

1. I created a new TagManager Account.
2. I added the Code to the head and body space on my website.
3. I created a Container.
4. I added a Google Analytics Tag
5. I created a Variable with exact the UA-XXXXX-**1** id for my property.

(I have dozens of different Google Analytics properties in my account.)

Now when I publish the Google Tag Manager changes, the Tag is published and visible. But it publishes a SECOND WRONG property-ID. UA-XXXXX-**2**.

Yes, the UA-XXXXX-**2** is also in MY ACCOUNT. But a complete **different** Website property!

I have no clue where the TagManager - which is setup completely new - gets the ID from another property. I didn't provide that ID anywhere (the property is archived).

The "Google Tag Assistant" is telling me that I have multiple Tags implemented, but that could not be true.
Error Message: (Multiple Google Analytics tags detected)

How can I solve that?

Affected site `"www global-nights com"`

[image: Analytics]

[image: Tagmanager]

[image: Live Site Tag Assistant]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a GTM problem. The second account is bundled in a Javascript file (/cdn cgi/apps/head/6sJWcjIvV53_JPO8tyNGb15vJYg.js) included on the top of your page:

[image]

So I guess you should be looking into your Cloudflare settings rather than be looking at GTM.

Comment: Thank you so much!